# What happens when you try to rotate a system around not it's center of mass?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

What happens when you try to rotate a system around not it's center of mass?

Comment: The picture failed to load. It is not clear what you are asking in that case. Please add pictures.

Comment: Why would there be net force or not when they are just rotating? You drew the connector ``fulcrum" parallel to the y axis but said it is the z axis. Why are you saying that they would suddenly stop after a 180 deg turn? Either the connector disallows any turning, or they should keep turning after 180 deg, just that they could be made to stop by themselves. I am not sure you are using the word fulcrum correctly

Comment: I believe the common term for the phenomenon that will be experienced is "wobbling".

Comment: Why not just do the experiment?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the cylinders are long tubes, not short pancakes (Not that it matters). You might be making them rotate with a motor on the axis. We will assume the motor is massless for simplicity. We assume the system starts at rest.

You are right in the first picture. The system experiences no net force and no net torque because nothing external is acting on it. The system as a whole does not rotate rotate or move. That is two parts rotate equally in opposite directions. Various parts exert forces on each other. The center of mass does not move.

The same considerations apply to the second picture, but now it is harder to figure out where the center of mass is. Is it on the axis? If not, it is entirely possible that the axis moves.

Note that net rotation around the y axis is also impossible. But consider what happens if you rotate the tubes $90^o$. If the motor pushed the upper mass in the +z direction, the top of the axis must be pushed in the -z direction. The bottom mass is pushed in the -z direction and the bottom of the axis in the +z direction. The axis part rotates one way and the masses part rotates the opposite way.

Here is a fun example where these ideas matter. [Wrist rocket: worlds fastest disc launcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnwIiw3Rz3I) You can see that neglecting these ideas produced a launcher that could break your arm. Good thing he tested it!

Comment: Various parts exert forces on each other. The center of mass does not move. I didn't fully answer because this is a homework-like problem. You should think about it yourself.